# Cannot pass data through NavigationController

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to pass data from a UITableView when clicking on the cell. This is what I've written from a similar flow that worked, thinking it would work as well but it doesn't pass any data.

Here is the code:

```
extension PastBoxesViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let nextVC = GiftViewController()
        nextVC.title = "Gift Number \(indexPath.row)"
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

```
class GiftViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = ""
        self.view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8186396956, green: 0.7955000997, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

This method of passing data works outside a UITable, does it not work inside or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: please share the other part of the code

Comment: I added the GiftViewController code

Comment: did you set the delegate ?

Comment: I don't understand, you pass the string to the nextVC in your `didSelectRowAt` function but then you set the title back to " "  in `viewDidLoad` ? I am not sure the title property is available before the view is loaded. Have you tried to create a `var` and then set `self.title = yourVar` in `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong except that  in `GiftViewController` your are setting the title property to an empty string after your correctly assigned the value you want in `didSelectRowAt`. So you set the the property before the view is loaded and then when the view finish loading you change that value again to an empty string.

Just change your code in `viewDidLoad` removing that line of code and everything will be working fine:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   //self.title = "" your problem is here
   self.view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8186396956, green:  0.7955000997, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! What a dumb mistake lol

Comment: @ajnauleau glad it worked. Can you please accept the answer if it helped?